# I solved a circular dependency. Are there problems with the solution?

Tags: c++

I solved a circular dependency. It has been compiled by g++. Already existing solutions on the site don't include `include` in headers and just add `class ...;`. So, I want to know, are there any problems with the solution?

classA.h

```cpp
#ifndef CLASS_A_H
#define CLASS_A_H

class ClassB;

class ClassA {
public:
    ClassB* b;
    int get5();
};

#include "classB.h"

#endif
```

classB.h

```cpp
#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H

class ClassA;

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassA* a;
    int get7();
};

#include "classA.h"

#endif
```

classA.cpp

```cpp
#include "classA.h"

int ClassA::get5() {
    return 5;
}
```

classB.cpp

```
#include "classB.h"

int ClassB::get7() {
    return 7;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "classA.h"

int main() {
    ClassA a;
    std::cout << a.get5() << std::endl;
    ClassB b;   
    std::cout << b.get7() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are there any problems with the solution?

Defining `B` in the header classA.h is unnecessary, and vice versa.

This won't break anything, but can cause the translation units that include one of those headers to be recompiled when either of the definitions is changed even when those translation units did not depend on the transitively included definition.

Best practice is to only include headers that are necessary to be included.

---

Another issue is that in main.cpp, you depend on definition of `B` without including its definition directly. If you at some point change the definition of `A` to no longer depend on `B` in any way, and consequently remove the apparently unnecessary include, then main.cpp will fail to compile because it assumes that `B` is defined by including classA.h.

It is usually best practice to *directly* include headers that define dependencies and to not rely on transitive inclusions.

Answer (score 2):

That's an usual solution, except that you have unnecessary includes at the end of each of headers. Remove them, and in `main.cpp` include both `classA.h` and `classB.h`.

Comment: If I remove the "includes", I have to include "classB.h" each time when I use include "classA.h" and vice versa. What would be if classA has classC?

Comment: Not necessarily true. If you don't use methods of `ClassB` while using `ClassA`, you can avoid include, even if you call `get5`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru -- when you `#include "classA.h"` and you don't `#include "classB.h"` you can create objects of type `ClassA` and call `get5()` on those objects. Similarly, when you `#include "classB.h"` and you don't `#include "classA.h"` you can create objects of type `ClassB` and call `get7()` on those objects. Each class stands on its own.